# Appending Result from fetchall() multiple execution to a single DF and converting to a CSV, but in CSV unable to split the list into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, split

```
query = pd.read_csv('input_query.csv')
query_list = query['DB_QUERY'].tolist()
length = len(query_list)
result_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(length):
    sql1 = query_list(i)
    cusror1 = conn.cursor()
    cursor1.execute(sql1)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    result_d = pd.DataFrame(result)
    result_f = result_f.append(result_d)
 result_f.to_csv('output_result.csv',index =False,header=1)
```

Output is in the format (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHqHr.png)
0,1,2,3,4
booking,complete,Booking_Daily.snapshot,2021-07-31,2
booking,valid,Booking_Daily.snapshot,2021-07-31,97

Required Format(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMlD0.png) -
Values splitted in multiple columns instead of single column with column header.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(length):
    sql1 = query_list(i)
    cusror1 = conn.cursor()
    cursor1.execute(sql1)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    result_d = pd.DataFrame(result)
    result_d.to_csv('output_result.csv',index =False,header=1, mode=’a’)
```

A small explanation:
result_d is a data frame now so you can append it to a csv on every loop.

Alternatively:
You can append all fetch all results to a list by doing `all_results += result[0]` as fetchall returns a tuple of lists...

At the end of the loop you can convert all_results to a data frame and proceed to export as csv